# Putting recoil atom and selectors inside a class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

Currently we are using recoils atoms and selectors with no logical seperation and prefix. We do put them in seperate folders according to their state context but thats it. When I am calling a recoil atom or selector in my code in order to use it I need to remember that the name of this atom has to do with changing a certain part of state.

For example if the state I am dealing with curremtly is "TODOS" and I need a "counter" atom I need to call it "todosCounter".

I would like to have a different approach with it I can call it like "todos.counter" so I was thinking of placing the recoil atoms and selectors inside a class and male them static. ChatGpt opinion was that it violates the "seperation of concerns" principle but I can't unserstand why.

So to make things short, Is it considered to be a good practice to put the recoil atoms inside a class as static variables? I will be more than happt if there is another way to prefix the atoms for semantic grouping and order

This is how I want to set the atoms:

```
class State1 {
  static atom1 = atom({
    key: 'atom1',
    default: '',
  });

  static atom2 = atom({
    key: 'atom2',
    default: '',
  });

  static selector1 = selector({
    key: 'selector1',
    get: ({ get }) => {
      // selector logic
    },
  });

  static selector2 = selector({
    key: 'selector2',
    get: ({ get }) => {
      // selector logic
    },
  });
}
```

and call them like so:

```
const atom1Value = useRecoilValue(State1.atom1); // Accessing atom1 value
const selector1Value = useRecoilValue(State1.selector1); // Accessing selector1 value
```